# How to add Authorization in Header for Get method in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add my token in Authorization header

```
NSURL *url2 = @"http://54.149.31.77:3000/api/search?number=98745612661";

        NSLog(@"%@  urlis ====>",urlString);

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
        NSString *ret = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *dataaa = [ret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataaa options:0 error:nil];
        NSArray * resultDict =[json objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSMutableRequest -

```
  NSURL *url2 = @"http://54.149.31.77:3000/api/search?number=98745612661";
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url2];

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

  [request setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   // add any additional headers or parameters
   NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
   // do your response handling
   id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray * resultDict =[json objectForKey:@"name"];
  }
  }];

  [downloadTask resume];
```

To understand in more detail about NSURLSession refer to this [Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394)

Comment: Added session initialization as well. Its how you call your webservice. Older APIs used NSURLConnection which is now deprecated and replaced by NSURLSession and its related tasks.

Comment: It depends on what data you want to pass in request. In your current code you have not shown any data so i have just used url to call the get method and i have assumed you have your token saved in NSUserdefaults. so you can replace that line form somewhere else. 

Your parsing of response i have added now which would be in completion handler. Let me know if you need anything else but this should suffice and work according to your needs

Comment: when add above code to my project it doen't not entering in to responce  means after calling the NSURLSessionDataTask , directly coming out to end point & also I'm not using downloadTask any where. it showing unused downloadTask.help me

Comment: You just have to add [downloadTask resume]; after your completion handler to start the request. I have added in the above code

Comment: @KarthikReddy My pleasure. Please accept my answer.

Comment: it is called very slowly. why this is happening

Comment: What do you mean by very slowly. Its a request to server so it will take some time for the server to respond. How slow is it? How much time does server take to respond. What part of the code is slow?

Comment: only first time responce is coming

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it by

```
[request setValue:@"Your Token" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

**Edited :**

As per your comment if you want to change your response then your should use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSArray` like.

Note: Your response should Dictionary if it will array then use `NSMutableArray`

```
NSMutableDictionary * resultDict =[json objectForKey:@"name"];
[resultDict setObject:@"Your Token" forKey:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: what is request in my code. can u explain how to declare & where can i declare request

Comment: it's object of NSMutableURLRequest class. I'm thinking you should learn from other tutorial to how to send request on server.

Comment: @KarthikReddy add your full code of how you are sending request so we will help you on that

Comment: the above mentioned code is my full code. I'm getting the my responce from resultDict but how can i add token to that code is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[request addValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Try to create a Mutable request and add your authorization header to it. You can send this request as a parameter to any one. Either to AFNetworking (or some third party network) library API calls or to URLSession (by Apple)

For more info on [NSMutableRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest)